# Nesting subscribe within formControl.valuesChange

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a subscription on the changing value of an input formControl and I need to take those values as the user types to make another call. This works but it feels wrong since I thought the point of observables was to rid callback hell. Any help?

```
  constructor(private symbolSearchService: SymbolSearchService) {
    this.symbolSearchForm = new FormControl();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.symbolSearchForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
      val => {
        this.symbolSearchService.symbolLookup(val).subscribe(
          val => console.log('val', val)
        )
      }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten this out using the observable operators:

```ts
this.symbolSearchForm.valueChanges
  .mergeMap(val => this.symbolSearchService.symbolLookup(val))
  .subscribe(val => console.log('val', val));
```

See e.g. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

Comment: thank you this works! btw you should edit to .mergeMap

Comment: you wrote margeMap :P

Comment: @Yeysides ah, whoops! Fixed, thanks. Note that you can suggest edits to answers if there's just a little typo like that.

Comment: it didn't let me bc the queue was full :o